# GET with request params or POST

Tags: rest, api, post, get

I have a GET endpoint to get a set of resources and a custom request param 'filter' to filter the said resources.  This param is a stringified array of filters.  Due to the [length limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string) in request param, I couldn't provide large filters.  So, I had to opt for POST with filters in body.  But, as POST requests are [not idempotent](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch04s11.html), it seems highly deviating from API standards. I have searched a few sites and couldn't come up with a solution.  Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about hitting the length limitation, then you have to use `POST`. Yes, that means you lose idempotence and [safety](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), which is unfortunate, but there aren't other good choices.

Comment: Guess I have no choice then. Thanks Eric.